# Interpolation values are not coming correct using numpy and scipy python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I am doing interpolation on two different dataset , one value is coming correct other one is wrong.

[image: values are correct for this data]
**print(np.interp(4,  x,y))**
f_interp1 = interp1d( x,y)
print(interp1d(4)
**result is 116.6796391**
[image: values are wrong for this data]

**print(np.interp(4,  x,y))**
f_interp1 = interp1d( x,y)
result is **15.932553369231139** it should be **15.13196509**

Comment: `15.932...` is correct.  You can check the linear interpolation with a simple calculation: `15 + (4 - 3.991222)*(121 - 15)/(4.989027 - 3.991222)` gives `15.932514870139952`.

Comment: It looks like you used the wrong interval to compute the slope when you got `15.13196509`.  Here is the *incorrect* calculation: `15 + (4 - 3.991222)*(15 - 0)/(3.991222 - 2.993416)`.  It gives `15.131959519185092`.  `(15 - 0)/(3.991222 - 2.993416)` is the wrong slope for the interval containing 4.

Comment: Yes you are right.Thank you